# php pdo - Split fetch() return into Variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, pdo

I have the following PHP PDO code:

```
$sql='SELECT a,b,c FROM my_table WHERE d=?;';
$pds=$database->pdo->prepare($sql); $pds->execute(array($d_value)); $row=$pds->fetch();
echo $row['a'];
```

this works fine.

I wanted to know how I could break all 3 return values in the fetch() into variables in one line. I have tried this unsuccessfully:

```
$sql='SELECT a,b,c FROM my_table WHERE d=?;';
$pds=$database->pdo->prepare($sql); $pds->execute(array($d_value)); $row=$pds->fetch();
list($a,$b,$c) = $row[0];
echo $a
```

how do I get the 'list($a,$b,$c) = $row[0];' line to work?

thankyou very much :)

Comment: thought I had seen a quick way to break them into variables using one line... named variables would be good as I will be using them a lot in the code below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
list($a,$b,$c) = $row;
```

With $stmt->fetch() only return one row. no need to reference $row[0]

Comment: yes that is it... sorry silly question but I just wasn't sure... greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be....

```
   list($a,$b,$c) = $row;
```

Not $row[0];

Answer (score 0):

[Set PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC first](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info), and then

```
$sql = 'SELECT a,b,c FROM my_table WHERE d=?';
$pds = $database->pdo->prepare($sql);
$pds->execute(array($d_value));
if ($row = $pds->fetch()) {
    extract($row);
}
echo $a;
```

Answer (score -1):

`$stmt->fetch()` doesn't work for me, because *it returns an `associative array with keys` equal to the column names*

My solution to get the values from an associative array first:

```
list($a, $b, $c) = array_values($stmt->fetch());
```